# Page content differs from editor

Tags: 7

I've inherited Drupal 7 website. I'm having some difficulties figuring out why one of the pages is showing different content then it actually has in the edit page.

This site is multilingual (3 languages), same page is displaying properly on 2 other languages. But on this one language instead of rendering proper content, that I see in the editor, it renders completely different content. This is the only page I'm having trouble with.

To be exact it shows sharing buttons instead of just plain text and hyperlinks content. These sharing buttons aren't supposed to be there in the first place.

This isn't a front page, just regular page created through add content > regular page.

Has anyone had successfully resolved the same/similar problem and could share knowledge?

Comment: Quick update. Share buttons seems to appear on every of these pages in the bottom, right after the content. So it means that the actual content of the page is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the developer did on the website. It could be very difficult if it is done by a developer who is not familiar with Drupal. For your situation, I can share some possible places of code for your reference.

Drupal developer may do it in:

- Preprocess function in theme template.php
- Field pre render function in custom module.

PHP developer may do it in:

- PHP condition code in node.tpl.php

Frontend developer may do it in:

- DOM manipulation in theme js file.